# Search a Map using getString(R.string.my_string)

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a localized Android application and I have a Map.

I'm going to have a Map with `getString(R.string.my_string)` as **key**, and an **int** as a value.

I'm wondering if I can do that because the app is going to be localized and I'm not sure if it is a good idea use `getString(R.string.my_string)` as key.

**What do you think?** I need to search values using the string returned by `getString(R.string.my_string)`.

I need because the user will select a value on a `Spinner`. The selected item in the Spinner is a `String`, and need to use this `String`to get the value associated.

Comment: Are you asking if this is feasible or if it would be a good design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. It's just a mapping from `String` to `int`.

Is it a good idea? I don't think so, since `String` from `getString(R.string.my_string)` can vary depending on the localization. In the [`onItemSelected()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) you have `int position` of the selected item. Use this as your key.

Comment: If I do that, from the Spinner I will get a `String`. With this `String`, how can I know its `R.string.my_string`?

Comment: Care to explain your reasons? Otherwise this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I forget to say that the items in the `Spinner` **must be ordered alphabetically**, so I can't use `position`.

Comment: What is the purpose of your map? This `int value` - what is it? Because if the Map is created on a particular device, without connection to other devices (which can have different localization), `getString()` will return always the same `String` and such mapping will have sense.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk I will use the int value associated with each string to send it to a web service. For example, I have a Spinner to select a stature: tall, average and small. On every language I'll have a localized string, but I need to send its int value to identify it.